# Get custom attributes form lambda expression

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Suppose something like this :

```
public static IQueryable<T> Find<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string value, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] subSelectors) where T : class
{
   foreach (var include in subSelectors)
   {
     var entityType = include.Body.Type.GetGenericArguments().First();
     var properties = from p in entityType.GetProperties()
                      where Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(FilterAttribute))
                      select p;
   }
}
```

This method is called from another assembly, exemple call of this method :

```
     var container = new List<MyClass>();
     var q = (from m in container
              select m).AsQueryable();
     SimpleFilter.Find(q, "something", m => m.Navigation);
```

For the T parameter is ok I see my custom attribute. But form the lambda expression I cant see my custom attribute.

Comment: btw... `entityType` is simpler as `typeof(T)` here, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to see if each selector specified has the attribute:

```
var member = ((MemberExpression) include.Body).Member;
bool hasAttribute = Attribute.IsDefined(member, typeof (FilterAttribute));
```

it isn't clear how you intend to plug that into the rest of the `Find` method, but I **think** that covers the main thrust of the issue.